# Detection of vue components finish rendering

Tags: api, vue.js, components, rendering, loading

On one of the pages of my website, there are number of API calls which brings data for the AmCharts chart components.
While API calls are being returned, I set `isLoading` flag to be true on this page and show a loading spinner. 
And as the API call is finished, I change `isLoading` value to false, thus the charts are then rendered.

But still, there is a significant delay on the page when isLoading changed to false, showing a white screen for a few or even more seconds before the charts appear.

Here's the code snippet.

```
data() {
  return {
    isLoading: true
  }
},

mounted() {
  await API_calling();

  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.isLoading = false;
  }
}
```

I believe this delay is due to the AmCharts rendering time, and I want to set `isLoading` value to false when all the charts finish rendering.

So my question to stackoverflow is, how can I detect the moment when vue components finish rendering?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a few component loading simultaneously then the best way would be using vuex.

You can store to vuex 2 values: `isLoading` and `countLoadingComponents`.

You can increment `countLoadingComponents` at beginning of `created()` method of each component and decrement `countLoadingComponents` when API call within that component is finished.

Create `watcher` for `countLoadingComponents` state in the main component. If `countLoadingComponents` equal 0, then change state of `isLoading` to `false`.

Comment: API call is made in a parent component only and all the child components are using that data via vuex